# Nested MySQL GROUP BY Commands

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a MySQL query using a hierarchy of GROUP_BY commands. 
I would like to take a table and group by the FRUIT  & COLOR columns.

Then, I would like to create a new column "New?' that looks at the DATE column for all instances of the fruit (thereby grouping by just FRUIT -- regardless of color), and checks if the Date = 3.6.15 for ALL instances of that fruit. If that is true, "Yes" is assigned to all rows of that fruit; otherwise, "No" is assigned to all rows of that fruit.

My table currently looks like this:

```
FRUIT    COLOR    DATE    
Apple    Red      3.6.15
Apple    Green    3.6.15
Pear     Yellow   3.2.15
Melon    Red      3.6.15
Melon    Red      3.2.15
Grapes   Purple   3.6.15
Grapes   Green    3.4.15
```

Here is the new view I would like to create:

```
FRUIT    COLOR    NEW?  
Apple    Red      Yes
Apple    Green    Yes
Pear     Yellow   No
Melon    Red      No
Grapes   Purple   No
Grapes   Green    No
```

Any help in how I could go about achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What code have you done so far?

Comment: Note that dates in SQL adhere to a specific format

Comment: Did you try any of the answers?

Comment: @user3882316 If the answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. There's of course no obligation to do so, but doing it awards rep to both you and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregations inside a `case` statement:

```
select fruit, color,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.color = t.color and date <> '2015-03-06')
             then 'no'
             else 'yes'
        end) as IsNew
from table t;
```

This just checks for a date that is not the current date.  A record should exist, because the subquery is on the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join to do this. The joined table will return a non null value for all fruits that have more than one date, and the case expression uses that to determine if the fruit is new or not:

```
select 
    t1.FRUIT, 
    t1.COLOR,
    case when t1.date = '3.6.15' and t2.DATE is null 
      then 'Yes' 
      else 'No' 
    end as "New?"
from fruits t1
left join fruits t2 on t1.FRUIT = t2.FRUIT and t1.DATE <> t2.DATE;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6059f/4)

Comment: sorry, i realized one slight flaw to this solution. In the case where I have more than one identical record for instance with: Apple    Red      3.6.15, even though Apple should still technically be marked with "Yes" for "NEW?", it is not being marked as new. Is there a fix for this? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; if you add another row for `apple red 3.6.15` it will still be marked as new as it will be excluded in the left join and thus fulfill the `t2.date is null` predicate. See this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/926c5/1